# Ajax/Axios cookies not being set, but still being included in following requests

Tags: javascript, django, cookies, axios

For some reason cookies set by server are not being saved, can't access them from within my js code, in devtools in Application tab in cookies section it's all empty, but somehow when I make a request to the server after the initial one, those cookies that apparently didn't save are being included in the header.

I have set `withCredentials` to `true` in axios config, as well as `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` to `true` on my backend.

Here are the headers from the request that should save cookies:

```
Response Header:

access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: <frontend url>
content-length: 22
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 01 Feb 2021 12:04:09 GMT
server: nginx/1.19.2
set-cookie: csrftoken=<token>; expires=Mon, 31 Jan 2022 12:04:09 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
set-cookie: sessionid=<sessionid>; expires=Mon, 01 Feb 2021 13:04:09 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=3600; Path=/
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
vary: Cookie, Origin
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN

Request Headers:

:authority: <backend url>
:method: POST
:path: /login/
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 66
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
dnt: 1
origin: <frontend url>
pragma: no-cache
referer: <current frontend url query>
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
```

As you can see in the response I'm getting two cookies to be set, `sessionid` and `csrftoken`, those are not being saved.

What's weird those cookies are present in the following request:

```
Request Headers:

:authority: <backend url>
:method: GET
:path: /numbers/
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: csrftoken=<token>; sessionid=<sessionid>
dnt: 1
origin: <frontend url>
pragma: no-cache
referer: <current frontend url query>
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
```

How is it possible for the cookies to not be set but still included in the request? And what can cause this behavior? I really need them to be saved.

My backend and frontend are located at different urls, my backend is running on Django with a rest-framework.

**UPDATE**

I've also tried to set samesite on the cookies to none, as well as changing request `content-type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After hours spent troubleshooting this problem I found out a solution, somewhat. My frontend app and backend app are hosted from different urls, but under the same domain, like that: `<frontend>.<mydomain>.com` and `<backend>.<mydomain>.com`

When frontend application was making a request to the backend, backend was sending `set-cookie` headers that would save the cookies under `<backend>.<mydomain>.com` (I was able to confirm this in here: `chrome://settings/siteData`), which made them inaccessible from within `<frontend>.<mydomain>.com`, I were able to fix that by adding a domain property to the `set-cookie` header that would point to `.<mydomain>.com`. To do that I had to create a middleware in Django that would add my predefined domain name to the cookies before being send back to the client.

I'm not really 100% happy with this because if my applications were served from different domains, I'm not sure if I could make the cookies work at all, since setting `set-cookie` to a different domain is not allowed by the browser.